# CRA not showing linting errors/warings from .ts and .tsx files in the console

Tags: reactjs, typescript, eslint

Project is bootstrapped with CRA without `--typescript`, then TS was added following `https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-typescript`.

`eslintrc` looks like this :

```
{
  "extends": ["plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended", "react-app"],
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 6,
    "sourceType": "module",
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "jsx": true
    }
  },
  "plugins": ["@typescript-eslint", "react"],
  "rules": {}
}
```

`tsconfig` is default. I did a `tslint --init` which added a default `.json` config.

Unused variables in `.js` files are shown in the console as a warning or error, but everything in `.ts` and `.tsx` files is ignored. Is there a way to have those show in the console as well?

If not, what's the best way to have linting errors show somewhere without having to type `eslint` every time.

Comment: Did you updated the react-scripts as well? They fixed this issue, check this link:

https://github.com/mozilla/addons-code-manager/issues/152